# Copy&Paste doesn't work on Mobile Safari and CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, clipboard, codemirror

I have wrote the following code:

```
function copy() {
  if(window.clipboardData) {
    window.clipboardData.clearData();
    window.clipboardData.setData("Text", document.getElementById('txtacpy').value);
  } 
}

function paste() {
  if(window.clipboardData) {   
    document.getElementById('txtapaste').value = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
  } 
}
```

When CodeMirror editor is focused I call:

```
paste();
```

But nothing happens! Browser is Mobile Safari. How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not supported in most browsers because of security issues without allowing a web page to have access to your clipboard.  This is not only Mobile Safari.  You won't find it supported in most browsers (like Chrome or Firefox).

Some people use a Flash work-around called [zClip/ZeroClipboard](https://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) that does allow copying to the clipboard, but only from a direct user click on the Flash object.  This is obviously not an option in mobile safari.

If you are only trying to move data around within your page, then you don't have to use the system clipboard to do that - you can create your own holding area for the data (a javascript variable) and put the data there upon Copy and retrieve it from there upon Paste.  Then, you use normal DOM functions (not copy/paste functions) to get the data from a field or to put the data into a field.

Comment: But how to fix the issue? How to paste to the focused element?

Comment: @Altaveron - I added a couple ideas to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think Flash isn't acceptable for Mobile Safari... And I need to work with system clipboard.

Comment: @Altaveron - I don't think you can do it from javascript on mobile Safari.  You can put the text into a field, pre-select it and ask the user to use the normal end-user convention for copying it to the clipboard.  That's life in a web application these days.